# how to recover folders from home folder

Tags: home-directory, remastersys

I was browsing net today..I had to upload a photo but I was unable to find the picture folder..then I opened nautilus.I found out that the 2 folders Pictures and Videos are mysteriously gone..I  totally have no Idea.There was REMASTERSYS running in background.How can I recover those 2 folders? and any idea how they got deleted?

Comment: search the trash can, maybe you accidentally deleted them. Or in a terminal type `locate -i Pictures`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many unanswered questions in this scenario. Have you checked that the folders haven't been moved, perhaps into the Ubuntu One folder? If deleted, you may have to use file recovery software such as 'foremost' to recover your files. Foremost can be run from the command prompt and with the -t switch can be set to only look for certain file types. The general syntax is: foremost -t (filetype to find) -i (input, or disk to be searched) -o (output, or destination for found data)

So for example if you wanted to search disk B for lost jpeg files and store the recovered data on a third disk the command might resemble:
foremost -t jpeg -i /dev/sdb -o /dev/sdc/folder

As for remastersys running, it's supposed to make a backup of your system as an iso file. Did you have it running for a reason, perhaps on a schedule? If so you might be able to mount a recent iso and copy your files out of there.

Comment: I think file recovery is the only option..I could not find any logical reasons for their disappearance.I searched but they are not moved anywhere :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use formost to recover files.

```
sudo foremost -i image -o /recovery/foremost
```

[Here is some more information on recovering files](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery)